# Delete a user in parse User table from windows 8.1 app

Tags: parse-platform

I am developing a windows 8.1 app using Parse as back-end, I want to delete a user from windows app,How to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

You can delete a user using Cloud Code.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("deleteUser", function(request, response) {
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    query.equalTo("objectId", reques.parsams.userId);
    query.first({
        success: function(result) {
            result.destroy({
                success: function() {
                    response.success("Success");
                }, 
                error: function(error) {
                    response.error("Could not delete object");
                }
            });
        },
        error: function() {
            response.error("Could not run query");
        }
    });
});
```

You'd call the above function in Windows 8, where xxxxxxx is the objectId of the user you'd like to delete.

```
IDictionary<string, object> params = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "userId", "xxxxxxx" }
};
var result = await ParseCloud.CallFunctionAsync<IDictionary<string, object>>("deleteUser", params);
```